# Table View items are not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am new to iOS development.

I'm trying to display a list of items in my app using `UITableView`, but the items are not showing:

[image]

My View Controller:

```
class HistoryView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var noDataLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(HistoryTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "historyCell")
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.noDataLabel.isHidden=true
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyCell") as! HistoryTableViewCell

        cell.nickname?.text = "name"
        
        return cell
    }

    
}
```

My Table View Cell:

```
class HistoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nickname: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Any suggestions for what's going on?

Comment: Is `numberOfRowsInSection` being called?  (Check with a `print` or breakpoint.)

Comment: check that your tableview isn't hidden

Comment: Are you using Prototype cells? If yes then you must not register the cell.

Comment: table view is not hidden

Comment: yes numberOfRowsInSection called 10 times

Comment: because of register its not showing thanks @vadian

Answer (score 1):

**condition 1:**
if you are using prototype cells remove the line

```
tableView.register(HistoryTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"historyCell")
```

and give cell identifier in the storyboard

[image]

**condition 2:**
if you are using xib file then register the cell like below:-

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HistoryTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "historyCell")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to register cell like this

```
tb.register(UINib(nibName: "HistoryTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "historyCell")
```

I saw `@IBOutlet weak var nickname: UILabel!`

in the `class HistoryTableViewCell`.

---

for table cells,

`dequeueReusableCell` and `register`, should called in pairs